# Reading result of Formula Cells in Apache POI 3.15

Tags: scala, apache-poi

I try to read the values from a cell as a String (as one would see it in Excel). I reads from a xlsx (`XSSFWorkbook`) using Apache POI 3.15.

My goal is e.g. to omit decimal point and trailing zeros if the cell contains an integer. This works for `CellType.NUMERIC`:

```
val dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(true) // set emulateCsv to true
val stringValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)
```

If I use the same code for `CellType.FORMULA` cell (e.g. a cell which references another "integer" cell), it just gives me the formula as a string instead of its computed value.

How can I get value of the formula-cell as displayed in Excel displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "evaluate" cells in order to get the result of formulas. This is not done automatically by POI as it can be a heavy operation and often will not be necessary.

See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html for details, basically you create a `FormulaEvaluator` and retrieve a `CellValue` for the Cell in question

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
...
CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I apply your solution, I actually get the cell value (in my case "2.0"), but not as displayed in Excel ("2"). To get the desired output, I needed to change it to this : `dataFormatter.formatCellValue(evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell))`

Comment: Yes, formatting is not done by the evaluator and thus done in a 2nd step the same way you format other cell-contents with the dataFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Centic and Raphael I ended up using the concept with NumberFormat to fix an issue, this is Java but I am sure it can easily be converted to Scala
The issue is around numbers with decimal places which produces scientific decimal points.
This was only required when converting Apache POI `XLS / XLSX` to `CSV` format

```
 //Create an evaluator from current work book
 FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  // Cell cell2 = evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
  // As per above get CellValue
  CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
  //Get Double Value of formula which may contain E numbers
  Double value = cellValue.getNumberValue();
 // This gets numberFormat (below function) and assigns correct formatting to it
 NumberFormat formatter = getNumberFormat(value);
//This should now be string value of number with correct decimal place values (non scientific)
 formatter.format(value)

/** 
* getNumberFormat takes number and either assigns #0 
* if no decimal places or 
* depending on how many numbers after decimal place assigns correct format
*/
public static NumberFormat getNumberFormat(Double value) {
    String v = value.toString();        
    String format = "#0";
    // This fixes scientific value issue
    if (v.contains(".")) {
        int decimals = v).substring(v.indexOf(".") + 1).length();
        //Calls generateNumberSigns based on decimal places in given double
        String numberSigns = generateNumberSigns(decimals);
        format = "0." + numberSigns;
     }
     return  new DecimalFormat(format);       
}
/**
* This will generate correct formula for amount of decimal places
*/
public static String generateNumberSigns(int n) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s += "#";
    }
    return s;
  }
```